# Syncing object passed to thread with timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I previously made a simple ball and paddle program all running in one form. Now I am trying to have the ball run on a separate thread, but don't quite understand conceptually how to have the ball run a separate thread while keeping the rest of my program the same.

Originally the timer would make the ball move, so I thought I can insert that move line into my ballUpdate class. But now my question is if there is a way to make the thread work my current timer implemented.

This is what my form1 looks like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics paper;
        Paddle paddle = new Paddle();
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        Thread myThread;
        BallUpdate ballUpdate = new BallUpdate();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myThread = new Thread(() => ballUpdate.ballMotion(ball));
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            paper = e.Graphics;
            paddle.drawPaddle(paper);
            ball.drawBall(paper);

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ball.moveBall();
            ball.collide();
            ball.hitPaddle(paddle.PaddleRec);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

I thought this might get something going, but the ball doesn't move at all.

```
class BallUpdate
{
    public BallUpdate(){}

    public void ballMotion(Ball x)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            x.moveBall();
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a loop to keep the thread running.

Comment: ...and Thread.Sleep accepts an integer timespan in milliseconds (1/10 == 0)

Comment: @Romoku Okay I just added a loop for x.moveball as well changed Thread.Sleep to 1. The ball still doesn't move though.

Comment: Well how was it working before?

Comment: Previously, I didnt have a thread. Instead, that ball.moveBall() was not commented out under the timer1. Now I am trying to get the ball motion converted to a new thread.

Comment: Do you call [`myThread.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx) anywhere?

Comment: When I try putting that under the new Thread statement, I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?

Comment: The program starts to run. Then after the form is displayed, the program stops and highlights this line (from the new Thread line) `ballUpdate.ballMotion(ball, paper)` and displays the message `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred` as well as the previous one I posted.

Comment: Paper isn't initialized yet. You should be doing your calculations for the ball's position on that thread and the drawing should be on the form thread.

Comment: Oh, I don't use paper anyways. Even when I remove paper , I still get the same error.

Comment: ballupdate isn't initialized either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26754/discussion-between-krikara-and-romoku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `ballUpdate` and start your `myThread`. Only the ball's logic should be on a separate thread.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics paper;
        Paddle paddle = new Paddle();
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        Thread myThread;
        BallUpdate ballUpdate = new BallUpdate();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myThread = new Thread(() => ballUpdate.ballMotion(ball));
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            paper = e.Graphics;
            paddle.drawPaddle(paper);
            ball.drawBall(paper);

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ball.moveBall();
            ball.collide();
            ball.hitPaddle(paddle.PaddleRec);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

In BallUpdate change `if(true)` to `while(true)` to prevent the thread from exiting. Incorporate delay so your ball doesn't go flying.

```
class BallUpdate
{
    public BallUpdate(){}

    public void ballMotion(Ball x)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            x.moveBall();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend building a thread method that loops over the following:

1. Calculate the Timespan in milliseconds since the last calculation
2. Move all the objects accordingly
3. Collision checking and resolving
4. Invoke the display method to render the frame
5. Return to Step 1

Please do not create a new thread in each frame, that will have abysmal performance. Also, do not manipulate graphics objects in a thread.